# Using js-ipfs in vue to upload and display images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ipfs

I am looking to use ipfs as the file store in a vue app, so that files are all stored locally. I am however struggling with understanding the vue demo and what exactly it does and how I move forward.

I am using vue cli gui so have imported latest js-ipfs as a dependancy and have built a component based on the demo code. https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/examples/browser-vue

```
   <div>
<h1>{{ status }}</h1>
<h2>ID: {{ id }}</h2>
<h2>Agent version: {{ agentVersion }}</h2>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueIpfs from 'ipfs'
//VueIpfs

export default {
  name: 'IpfsInfo',
  data: function () {
     return {
       status: 'Connecting to IPFS...',
       id: '',
  agentVersion: '',
}
   },
mounted: function () {
this.getIpfsNodeInfo()
 },
 methods: {
     async getIpfsNodeInfo() {
   try {
    // Await for ipfs node instance.
    const ipfs = await this.$ipfs
    // Call ipfs `id` method.
    // Returns the identity of the Peer.
    const { agentVersion, id } = await ipfs.id()
    this.agentVersion = agentVersion
    this.id = id
    // Set successful status text.
    this.status = 'Connected to IPFS =)'
  } catch (err) {
    // Set error status text.
    this.status = `Error: ${err}`
  }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

However I am not sure 1) how to adapt to latest vue / cli gui and then 2) next steps to get this to diplays images out of IPFS, I have the desktop app installed ? assuming I could call into that “bucket”

Any pointers appreciated a lot of the API stuff is out of my depth instantly atm

My understanding is that the example component can be used to spin up a IPFS node and then I use Vue upload forms to add to that IPFS node... that kind makes sense but I cant see if I am starting it correctly

Answer (score 0):

This worked

````
const ipfs = VueIpfs.create()


//  The below code should create an IPFS node to add files to
export default {
  name: 'IpfsInfo',
  data: function () {
    return {
      status: 'Connecting to IPFS...',
      id: '',
      agentVersion: '',
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    console.log(VueIpfs)
    this.getIpfsNodeInfo()
  },
  methods: {
    selectedFile(event) {
      this.file = event.target.files[0]
//TODO: Something like the below
      // console.log(this.file)
      //  ipfs.add(this.file)
    },
    async getIpfsNodeInfo() {
      try {
        // Await for ipfs node instance.
        const node = await ipfs
        //console.log(ipfs)
        // Call ipfs `id` method.
        // Returns the identity of the Peer.
        const { agentVersion, id } = await node.id()
        this.agentVersion = agentVersion
        this.id = id
        // Set successful status text.
        this.status = 'Connected to IPFS =)'
      } catch (err) {
        // Set error status text.
        this.status = `Error: ${err}`
      }
    },
  },
}```
````